# Cannot Login sqlbuddy on Ubuntu localhost

Tags: ubuntu, localhost, sqlbuddy

I installed lamp server into my Ubuntu 16.04 via tasksel. After then I downloaded sqlbuddy and set it up to /var/www/html.

I called following link (localhost/sqlbuddy) that appeared SqlBuddy Login Screen. I logged in as Username: root and left password field. But didn't go and appeared

```
This page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

What's wrong? How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Just had same issue.

The problem is that SQLBuddy is not compatible with PHP7.
You can find a compatible version here: https://github.com/Frecuencio/sqlbuddy-php7